# Weird behavior on Arduino Built in led

Tags: c++, c, arduino, i2c, led

I'm starting to program in Arduino and I tried to connect two cards using the I2C bus, as it appears in this [tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter). I would like that every time the slave card receives a byte from the master, the built in led of the slave blinks (it should turns on for a second and then turns off).  The problem is that, in practice, the led blinks in a very strange way (it's a very fast blink, much less than a second), it doesn't stay on for a second. Any idea why this could be happening?

Here is the code:

**Master:**

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
}


void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(4);
  Wire.write(1);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(5000);
}
```

**Slave:**

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(4);
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  int x = Wire.read(); // without this, it doesn't work
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);  
}
```

**PD:** I have checked that the led works correctly with a program that turns it on and off in the loop.

Thank you!

Comment: Your receiveEvent is called in an interrupt context.  You can't have a delay call in an ISR.  Set a flag in the ISR and blink the LED in loop in response to the flag.

Comment: See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/68431/53587 for a similar question and solution

Comment: Thank you both very much! I didn't know about the interruptions, now everything works fine